# Cannot edit generated excel file

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

**Problem**: 
In installed **Office 2010 computer**, my app have to copy an empty excel file (file A) to new excel file (file B) and use OpenXML library (V2.5) to execute some action, finally saved to hard disk. After that I open file B and just add a litle bit data (for example: 1) to it and save and close it. 
when I reopen file B, excel thrown an error: **Excel found unreadable content in ' file B' do you want to recover the contents of this workbook...** and I can not open it.
Below is my code:

```js
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExportDataSet(@"C:\A.xlsx",@"C:\");
}
public static void Copy(String oldPath, String newPath)
{
    FileStream input = null;
    FileStream output = null;
    try
    {
        input = new FileStream(oldPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        output = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        var buffer = new byte[32768];
        int read;
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (input != null)
        {
            input.Close();
            input.Dispose();
        }
        if (output != null)
        {
            output.Close();
            output.Dispose();
        }
    }

}

public static string ExportDataSet(string filePath, string path, int startRow = 10)
{
    var pathToSave = path;

    if (!Directory.Exists(pathToSave))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToSave);
    var filename = pathToSave + Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(filePath);
    Copy(filePath, filename);
    var fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
    {
        using (var myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, true))
        {
            var workbookPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart;
            var Sheets = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            var relationshipId = Sheets.First().Id.Value;
            var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)myWorkbook.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            //workbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties = new CalculationProperties() { FullCalculationOnLoad = true };
        }
        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();
        return filename;
    }
}
```

I think the OpenXML library has something wrong.
Do you have any ideas? please share to me, thank you so much.
Remarks: 
1. the computer use Office 2010 to open Excel file
2. the file format is Excel workbook (.xlsx)
3. if the computer installed office with later version (2013, 2016), the problem was not appeared.

Comment: Not related to your problem, thats why I am not ading it to my answer, but you could handle your `FileStream` better, enclosing them in a using statement like you did with the workbook. That way you get sure you dont forget to dispose your resources, 'cause the framework already does it.

Comment: You are probably focusing on the wrong part of the code when looking for the problem, OpenXML library is widely used, so unlikely to fail. I believe your problem is within your `Copy(String oldPath, String newPath)` method.

Comment: @bradbury9 , I tried your code, but the problem was not resolve.

Comment: 1- Does the problem happen with files smaller than your buffer size? 2- Maybe there is a bug in Office 2010 that does not conform to xlsx format, being able to open it with 2013 and later points to the file being fine.

Comment: @bradbury9 I tried to copy empty excel file (file A) to new excel file (file B) without using OpenXML, after that I can open and edit file B normally without any problem. So I think problem in the code related to OpenXML.

Comment: Hard to tell without a deep knowledge of the API and without sample excels, but my best guess is that OpenXML SDK does write the files using a file format features that 2010 does not fully support but MS in later versions does support. I would suggest you filling a bug at MS providing sample documents. Maybe 2010 does not fully support ECMA-376, Second Edition and ISO/IEC 29500 standard

Comment: I assume `ExportDataSet` is doing more than you're showing here. Without seeing that code it's impossible to know what's causing the problem. The usual culprits are adding items in the wrong order, adding the same item more than once or not adding something that is required. If you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it'll help people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer reading and writting logic is wrong. [The second parameter is where it starts to read or write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.write?view=netframework-4.7.2) and you are passing it a zero value, so second iteration of the while is overwritting the content written in the first iteration thus you are getting corrupted data if the files are greater than your buffer size.

Your code should be similar to this:

```
var buffer = new byte[32768];
int totalRead = 0; // Variable to track where to write in the next while iteration
int read;
while ((read = input.Read(buffer, totalRead, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    output.Write(buffer, totalRead, read);
    totalRead += read; // Add to totalRead the amount written so next iteration does append the content at the end.
}
```